# Toolbar above keyboard Android

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

I´m trying to put two views on my Activity, but I just need show them when the Keyboard is open. How can I do that?

I was looking for a tutorial or something but I find more about iOS than Android. Also I put a toolbar as the last one element on my layout, but it doesn´t work. I would like to know if exists something like "android:above_keyboard"... I don´t know.

Thanks.

Edid to add an example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must implement a listener to catch when thekeyboard hides or shows:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


// Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "KEYBOARD VISIBLE");
    yourView.setVisible(yourView.VISIBLE);
} else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "KEYBOARD HIDDEN");
    yourView.setVisible(yourView.INVISIBLE);
}
}
```

Regarding the position of the last toolbar, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: I going to try this, I think it could works well, I just wanna put a toolbar over the keyboard, if I get this, I will be happy.

Comment: I tried, I going to looking for some info, I dont get anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "toolbar"?

Comment: If your toolbar is inside a LinearLayout, the view should modify the parameters of visibility. Please post your code and your layout.